# How do I initialize and cout an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I do have a problem with an array I am loading and I cout later on in the code.
The array is initialized as:

```
int array[51][2]={{1,2},{7,4},/* ... */ }
```

The dots imply the other 49 missing tuples.
Later on, when I just want to cout the array I use:

```
for(int k=0;k<nProducts;k++){
    for(int t=1;t<=T;t++){
        cout << array[k][t];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work at all. Visual Studio happily compiles the program, but when I run it (ConsoleApplication) it crashes at this point. When I comment out the "cout-part" it works fine. But I doubt the array is used as it should be in the rest of the code.

Could you help me somehow with that ? I just cannot find my mistake in any literature, which seems to perfectly do the same I do.

Comment: What is `nProducts` and `T`?

Comment: `int t=1` indices should start at zero `0`.

Comment: `for(int t=0;t<T;t++)` start `t` at `0` and only increment up to, but not including `T`

Comment: Change this part of the code `for(int t=1;t<=T;t++)` into this : `for(int t=0;t<T;t++)`.

Comment: thanks, copy looks good. But how do I do that for a multidimensional array without having to declare (in this case) 51 tuples first ?


@awesomeyi: nProducts is 51 and T is 2, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
for(int t=1;t<=T;t++)
```

To this:

```
for(int t=0;t<T;t++)
```

Indexes in C/C++/Java/etc. are between 0 and N-1.

Comment: That was my feeling, too. But it does not work either.
And if only cout a specific entry of the array, like d[1][1] it gives the first number of the second tuple for some reason.

Comment: Man, I spend hours writing detailed answers on interrupt service routines, thread synchronization, runtime performance issues, algorithms, virtual memory address space... and at the end of the day, I get all my points explaining segfaults and invalid indexing...

Comment: @SaschaTillmanns: What is `T`? Please explain how it gets its value and where it is used/created.

Comment: @SaschaTillmanns: So perhaps you should spend some time explaining in your question exactly what `nProducts` and `T` are initialized to or defined as...

Comment: @SaschaTillmanns: Actually, just go ahead and post your whole code. I doubt it's really that big. Perhaps just a main.cpp file? Exclude any functions that aren't used.

Comment: Thanks for the answers in such a short time. I tried to create a minimal example and during that the problem vanished somehow. I cannot recap why. Somehow it works perfectly fine now. My program still does not work in its entirety, but it is a couple of thousands lines cplex/concert code, so I will maybe do  new question for that when I have an idea where the problem comes from

Comment: @SaschaTillmanns - `I tried to create a minimal example and during that the problem vanished somehow.`  The problem is probably still there.  When you go out of bounds of an array, there is no guarantee how your program will run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I believe that he meant **after applying the suggested fix** (as he complained in one of the comments above that the problem still persisted after he had applied that fix).

Comment: No, it had nothing to do with the fix. I had the problem with and without the fix. Then I commented out loads of the code to do a minimal. Then it worked perfectly (of course only in the fixed version!). Commenting in everything again it still runs smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing indices that are out of bounds - the array is indexed from `0`, so the last valid index is `N-1`. When you try to access the element at index `N`, you get `IndexOutOfRangeException` which causes the termination of the program.